# Expected value of a variable after i trials where probability of each trial is determined based on outcome of prior trials

Tags: probability

Assume one wanted to model the spread of a virus as a function of number of encounters in a population of constant size $k$.  Also assume that the virus is perfectly contagious, i.e. if a person without the virus encounters a person with the virus, the person without the virus is guaranteed to be infected.  Finally, assume infected individuals never recover (i.e. remain persistently capable of spreading the virus) and the virus originates at a single source.

*Assuming random encounters between pairs of individuals, is there a closed-form solution for calculating the expected number of infected individuals $n$ after $i$ encounters?*

At time $t$ = 0, $n$ = 1.  For any given encounter, I guess(?) the probability of a new infection taking place is $P(I) = (\frac{n}{k} \times \frac{k-n}{k}) \times 2$, i.e. the probability that either one of the two individuals is infected, but not both.  Everytime an infection takes place, $n = n + 1$.  So to reiterate, is there then a way to calculate the expected value of $n$ after $i$ encounters, given that $n$ is variant across trials as a function of prior trials?

Apologies if my math is a bit amatuer here.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your encounter model? Is it synchronous? Are all the perfect matchings equally probable? And I suppose by "devices" you mean individuals?

Comment: @Hoda I'm not completely sure what you mean by synchronous and perfect matching (in this context).  If it helps, assume a serial queue of encounter events.  Each event selects two individuals (with replacement) at random from the $k$ individuals.  For any event, if one and only one of the two individuals is currently infected, the other becomes infected and $n$ increases by 1.  And yep, corrected "devices" to "individuals".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that now there are $x$ persons infected:

The probability P(x) that a new infection takes place is

$P(x)=(\frac{n}{k} \cdot \frac{k-n}{k-1}) \cdot 2$ (your denominator is not correct).

The number of infected persons after the next encounter is:

$x_{new}=P(x)\cdot(x+1)+(1-P(x))\cdot x$.

$x_{new}=\frac{k^2x+kx-2x^2}{k(k-1)}$

So, this is how we define A(t) as the number of persons infected after t encounters (for a given k):

$A(t+1)=\frac{k^2A(t)+kA(t)-2A(t)^2}{k(k-1)}$, $A(0)=1$

This is just a recursive function, not a close-form as you asked, but this is how you should begin.